# Can't install 7zip in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: software-installation, software-sources

When I try to install 7zip in the Ubuntu Software Center, it reports it is available from the Universe repository. I click on "Use this source", I authenticate and nothing happens.

This is the case for everything I try to install, although my internet connection is fine.

And when I run the command `sudo apt-get update` I get the following results:

```
Ign private-ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease 
Err archive.ubuntu.com saucy InRelease 
Err archive.ubuntu.com saucy Release.gpg Could not resolve 'hostname'
```

Update: [Reply to comment]

```
quinco@quinco-Compaq-Linux:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release i386 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release i386 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main restricted
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main restricted
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security universe
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security universe
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security multiverse
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main universe restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main universe restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy universe
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-proposed multiverse main restricted universe
```

Another Update:

```
quinco@quinco-Compaq-Linux:~$ cmake --version

The program 'cmake' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install cmake

quinco@quinco-Compaq-Linux:~$ sudo apt-get install cmake
[sudo] password for quinco: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package cmake is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'cmake' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: pls edit your question by add your fail commands, what ubuntu u use?

Comment: You can use the command: `sudo apt-get install  p7zip-full`. For more details, view [7Zip Install Ubuntu](https://www.tecrobust.com/install-7zip-extractor-compressor-linux/) article.

Answer (score 3):

Run this following commands to install 7Zip:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full p7zip-rar
```

Comment: Tried this, no go..

quinco@quinco-Compaq-Linux:~$ sudo apt-get install p7zip-full p7zip-rar
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package p7zip-full is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: Found the answer on Linux Questions, turned out to be an entry in the line in a file under /etc/apt/apt.conf/ called 01proxy

Acquire::http::Proxy "http://hostname:3142";

Commented out the line and now all OK..

Comment: +1; This solution works for me, I have used it for several years already. The name of the executable program in Ubuntu will be `7z`

Comment: Works great as of `08/2021`, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference you should learn to use apt-cache search to find install candidates. For example 'apt-cache search 7zip' will return a list of packages your system knows to reference this utility.

Comment: So how does this help me install this package?